# How to locate Textview on Imageview with background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to locate text on image like [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) example.
I tried Merge,FrameLayout,RelativeLayout but I got

> cannot cast error

I gave  layout_weight and height, but it does not solve my problem. Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#11ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F5F5F5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/feed_item_profile_pic"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" >
        </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:textColorLink="@color/link" />



   <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedImage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to locate `@+id/timestamp` over `@+id/feedImage1`. These are listview items, and some child has image and some has not.

I have to finish application ASAP for homework. I check almost all similar threads.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1236): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

When I do RelativeLayout I got this. When I do FrameLayout, I got it as a FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: Also, is that your whole layout? If so you are not closing all the `LinearLayout` tags

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime(1236): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`
When I do RelativeLayout I got this. When I do FrameLayout, I got it as a FrameLayout$LayoutParams .  All tags are closed, I did not copied, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can place a Drawable on any TextView with the following API call: setCompoundDrawables().  This allows you to place an image next to your TextView, without requiring a specific layout, or additional controls.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29

Comment: Sorry I could not understand. I want to locate textview over imageview. Can you give me any example?